# Launch a smarty function by clicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, smarty

I am playing around with smarty and jquery...

Actually I have a bit lager project and I want to improve my source for better handeling.

Now what I have is a HTML-Page (`.tpl`) with some content. In one line I have a checkbox like:

```
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." checked>
<button onclick='fnTest({$options})'>test</button>
```

And because I want to call a js-function and pass some data via JSON I have a row in this page that looks like:

```
{$options = '{"preview":1, "extra_paper":0}'}
```

what actually simply creates a Smarty-Variable containing a JSON-String.

On my jsFile is simply use `console.log()` (at the moment) to see whats passed.

```
function fnTest(obj){
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Everyting is fine until here. Now I want to change some in the JSON-String as soon as I check/uncheck the checkbox.

Checked:

```
{$options = '{"preview":1, "extra_paper":1}'}
```

Unchecked

```
{$options = '{"preview":1, "extra_paper":0}'}
```

I tried to use a Smarty-Function

```
{function name=presets}
    //some source to write the JSON-String new
    {$data}
{/function}
```

that is called like

```
{presets data="checkstatus"}
```

but the problem here is, i don't know how to launch this function on a checkbox action...

May there is an other way to do this what im trying to do...

So the main Questions are:

**Is there a possibility to lauch a Smarty-Function on checkbox-event ?**

**Is there any way to recreate the JSON-String on the template and pass it to the function?**

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript code is not aware of how HTML was generated, whether from PHP/Smarty or any different ways.

What you can do, is to make an AJAX call to your server in order to get new generated HTML, and inject it wherever you want:

```
$('.yourCheckbox').change(function(event){

  // you get 'someParam' from either your checkbox status, or from the surrounding form...it's up to you
  $.get('path/to/your/script', { someParam : someValue }, function(data){

    // inject received html into a proper div
    $('someSelector').html(data);

  });

});
```

Then you need to learn about, among the other things:

- not writing inline js [e.g. `onclick=...`;
- using proper routing system, and not plain `path/to/myScript.php`.

Comment: Thx for this hint. Actually I don't need to learn this. Like I sayed it is a bit large project and 99% there is no onClick. The elements have classes and they get binded to clickevents. But in some cases (very rare) there is this type of code needed because otherwise it would be a lot of work to handle a simple thing. And than some other customers might run into some problems :) And Injecting the code is not actually this what I want. I will usse [sessionstorage](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is using [SessionStorage](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) since all useres in this project have to upgrade they're browser anyway. And actually its binded to Chrome so the is the best way passing some JSON-Strings to a JS-Function in this case.

With this I can call JS-Functions on Check-Event that gets/sets data to the Storage and later is easily can get it to decide what to do further.

Thanks for your help :)